# What is the purpose of NamedDomainObjectContainer in gradle?

Tags: version, gradle, containers

I read the documentation of Gradle about NamedDomainObjectContainer , but can't understand  how to use it. I want to add a property to my build and to understand when its value changes.

> def myContainer = project.container(MyClass.Name)
>
> myContainer.create(..)

but how to check when it's value changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain object container is a collection of named elements. Among other things, it can notify you if an element is added to or removed from the container. Gradle doesn't provide a built-in way to be notified when the value of an arbitrary property changes.

Comment: 1. So, how to understand if the property is changed ?
2. Can you give simple example of using of NamedDomainObjectContainer?

Comment: Ad 1. I don't understand the question. Ad 2. `def c = project.container(MyClass); c.all { elem -> /* do something whenever an element is added */ }`

Comment: How to understand if a value of a property is changed. When I have proeprty _sampleProp_ and in the build script I write:
sampleProp=10 I use set method to set is value right?? so I want to be notified when this is happend.

Comment: There is no special Gradle feature for that. If this is a user-declared property, there is no good way for you to get notified. If it's part of your own class, you can just declare an appropriate setter.

Comment: It's a convention property added from a custom plugin. So I just have to create setMyprop(String value){...} in the convention class and define what I want?